# negation of statement of simple expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am wondering what is the negation of the following statement:

$\forall x : a < x < b $

Even though it looks like mega simple task, the best what comes to my mind, is:

$\exists x: (x \leq a) \lor (x\geq b)$

Is this correct negation?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. To negate a $\forall$, you just need to say that there's one $x$ that disproves it, i.e. that your $x$ doesn't fit the predicate exactly. Which, in this case, means it's outside the boundaries $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is correct. More formally,

$$
\forall x : a < x < b
$$

means

$$
\forall x: [\ (a < x)\ and\ (x < b)\ ]
$$

so its negation would be

$$
\neg \forall x: [\ (a < x)\ and\ (x < b)\ ] \Leftrightarrow \\
\exists x: \neg [\ (a < x)\ and\ (x < b)\ ] \Leftrightarrow \\
\exists x: [\ \neg(a < x)\ or\ \neg(x < b)\ ] \Leftrightarrow \\ 
\exists x: [\ (a \geq x)\ or\ (x \geq b)\ ]
$$

which is the same thing as what you wrote.

Comment: Good answer. Two small quibbles, just to help you better communicate stuff: (1) it's -> its. (2) you probably want two-way double-arrows in that second block (3) you can actually put that hanging comma right after the second equation (before the `$$`!), and it'll appear in a more typographically familiar place.

Comment: Good points! Thank you